# throwValidationException method does not exist

Tags: laravel

I'm following a tutorial for laravel 5.5 on over overriding the REGISTER method in RegisterController, but i am getting error saying "Method [throwValidationException] does not exist on [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController]", not sure why?

```
<?php
/**
*  Over-ridden the register method from the "RegistersUsers" trait
*  Remember to take care while upgrading laravel
*/
public function register(Request $request)
{
    // Laravel validation
    $validator = $this->validator($request->all());
    if ($validator->fails()) 
    {
        $this->throwValidationException($request, $validator);
    }
    // Using database transactions is useful here because stuff happening is actually a transaction
    // I don't know what I said in the last line! Weird!
    DB::beginTransaction();
    try
    {
        $user = $this->create($request->all());
        // After creating the user send an email with the random token generated in the create method above
        $email = new EmailVerification(new User(['email_token' => $user->email_token, 'name' => $user->name]));
        Mail::to($user->email)->send($email);
        DB::commit();
        return back();
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        DB::rollback(); 
        return back();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: add use ValidatesRequests;  trait

Comment: Still getting the same error for some reason.

Comment: are u following laravel 5.3  lectures while having another version installed ? Prolly u dont wanna throw an exception to the user, instead u wanna display the exceptios so do following: if($validator->fails()     return redirect('post/create')
                        ->withErrors($validator)
                        ->withInput(); )

Comment: that is not a tutorial for Laravel 5.5 ... as that method no longer exists. You can't follow a tutorial that is using a different version of Laravel than you do unless you know all the differences between the versions, or you will run into problems like this.

Comment: im not really sure why you are overriding this method at all, as there is no need to ... after registration a `Registered` event is fired that you can listen to ... that is where any code needed to run after a successful registration should go

Comment: @SeanO exactly what lagbox said!

Answer (score 11):

as laravel 5.5 main contrller for register, you can use only this line:

```
$this->validator($request->all())->validate();
```

insted of these lines

```
$validator = $this->validator($request->all());
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            $this->throwValidationException($request, $validator);
        }
```